# Pandas reading csv files with partial wildcard

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write a script that imports a file, then does something with the file and outputs the result into another file.

`df = pd.read_csv('somefile2018.csv')`

The above code works perfectly fine. However, I'd like to avoid hardcoding the file name in the code.

The script will be run in a folder (directory) that contains the `script.py` and several csv files.

I've tried the following:

`somefile_path = glob.glob('somefile*.csv')`

`df = pd.read_csv(somefile_path)`

But I get the following error:

`ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>`

Comment: somefile_path is a list. loop for each element if list(file name) and then read it

Comment: Oh right. That's what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`glob` returns a list, not a string.  The `read_csv` function takes a string as the input to find the file.  Try this:

```
for f in glob('somefile*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    ...
    # the rest of your script
```

Answer (score 7):

To read all of the files that follow a certain pattern, so long as they share the same schema, use this function:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

def pd_read_pattern(pattern):
    files = glob.glob(pattern)

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for f in files:
        df = df.append(pd.read_csv(f))

    return df.reset_index(drop=True)

df = pd_read_pattern('somefile*.csv')
```

This will work with either an absolute or relative path.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list of the CSV files in the script and loop over them.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
mypath = os.getcwd()

csvfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f)) if '.csv' in f]

for f in csvfiles:
    pd.read_csv(f)
# the rest of your script
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over each file and build a list of DataFrame, then assemble them together using `concat`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this as the other bits didn't quite work for me, a new user.
The below code works and is easy to copy and paste.

```
csv_file_path = glob.glob('./*.csv')
list_into_strings = ''.join(csv_file_path)
df_in = pd.read_csv(list_into_strings)
```

I've tested this many times for single files. Not sure about multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

We will start useing concat from now on as append will be remove in feature release.

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
def read_pattern(patt):
    files = glob(patt)
    # Create empty dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for f in files:
        # Concat Instead of append
        df = pd.concat([df,pd.read_csv(f, low_memory=False)])
    return df.reset_index(drop=True)
df = read_pattern('*.csv')
```

Given the particular path

Comment: I like to append the `DataFrame` into a list and then concat them all at once for large lists as indicated by Zeugma. It would avoid the low_memory issue.