# Accessing CSV in python when file name is unknown

Tags: python, pandas

My python code is in directory 'MAIN'.
Inside MAIN, I have a folder 'DATA'.

Inside DATA, I have a CSV file and another folder '_OLD'

I want to import the CSV in DATA folder into a pandas dataframe, but I'm unsure of it's name.

How can I do that?

NOTE: There will always be exactly one CSV and the _OLD folder in the DATA folder. Thus I need a way to access the only file in that folder.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I had no idea how to go about this problem, still a beginner. Got the answer though. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do:

```py
from glob import glob
filename = glob("MAIN/DATA/*.csv")[0]
```

EDIT: Another way is to use the `pathlib` library. One difference is that the `glob()` method of the `Path` object returns a generator of files in the given directory. The objects that are emitted are `Path` objects (that can be converted to string if needed using the `str` string constructor.

```py
from pathlib import Path

for filename in Path("MAIN/DATA").glob("*.csv"):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
files = os.listdir('DATA')
filtered_files = [file_  for file_ in files if file_.endswith('.csv')]
df1 = pd.read_csv('DATA'+'/'+filtered_files[0])
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly, also let's me access the name of the file for later use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wildcard to import it.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49898878/2570277) answer, you can use the following code:

```
for f in glob('somefile*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    ...
```

This will not result in an error

Comment: it will definitely throw FileNotFoundError