# Search (in folders and subfolders ) and read files to a list of dataframes, using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a code

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('DIRECTORY\\file.xlsm', sheetname='Resume', header=1, usecols='A:I')
#some operations
```

```
bf1 =pd.read_excel('DIRECTORY\\file.xlsm', sheetname='Resume', header=1, usecols='K:P')
#some operations
```

`Final_file = pd.concat([df1,bf1], ignore_index=True)`

Note that df and bf are reading the same file, the difference is the columns being read.

I have a lot of files.

Is it possible to go through folders and subfolders, search for a filename pattern and create a list of dataframes to read, instead of writing each path I have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas reading csv files with partial wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898742/pandas-reading-csv-files-with-partial-wildcard)

Comment: No, not entirely because I am in one main folder, I want to go through subfolders, but I don't want to search outside the main folder.
However your suggestion is a good reading and helps to understand how some libraries work. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a recursive method with both `pathlib` and `glob`

note `parent_path` should be the top level folder you want to search.

```
from pathlib import Path

files = [file for file in Path(parent_path).rglob('*filename*.xls')]
```

this will return a list of files that match your condition. you can then cocnat a list comp.

```
dfs = [ pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Resume', header=1, usecols='A:I') for file in files]

df1 = pd.concat(dfs)
```

## Edit Latest File by Modified Time.

We can use the following function to take in a path and return a list of pathlib objects to get the latest modified time, we do this by splitting on a delimiter to get a unique file so sales_v1, sales_v2, sales_v3 will all become sales.  We then get the latest modified file from the three.

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
def get_latest_files(path):

    files = {
        f: pd.Timestamp(f.stat().st_mtime, unit="s") for f in Path(path).rglob("*.csv")
    }

    df = (
        pd.DataFrame.from_dict(files, orient="index")
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={"index": "path", 0: "seconds"})
    )

    df["dupe_files"] = df["path"].apply(lambda x: x.stem).str.split("_", expand=True)[0]

    max_files = (
        df.groupby(["dupe_files", "path"])
        .max()
        .groupby(level=0)["seconds"]
        .nlargest(1)
        .to_frame()
        .reset_index(-1)["path"]
        .tolist()
    )
    return max_files
```

Comment: It worked well. Thank you. I just had to edit `sheetname` to `sheet_name`.
I don't know if I can make another question here, but it is related: if I have multiple files in one folder with the same name but different versions e.g. "filename v2", is it possile to choose the latest version? (I also need not to write that version by hand because the folder is being updated almost daily)

Comment: Ok I will try to implement your suggestion, but will wait for your answer.
 (In the meantime, if I can achieve this output I will tell you)
So I will try to split the name `filename v#` and choose the maximum `#`

Comment: It has to be implemented using `filename name v#` and not by `modified date`, because I cannot make sure the previous versions aren't being edited.

Comment: I couldn't solve it because I can only find posts regarding the file `modified date`.
What I am thinking is to use your code : `files` and in `.rglob('*filename*v*.xls')]` and somehow after `v*` put some method to get the highest number in each subfolder

Comment: I tried some things, but I cannot figure it out. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Sorry to bother again, the output from the edit that I am getting is the overall last file.
I will explain. I have a subfolder for each year  "2018 folder", "2019 folder" and "2020 folder", and what I am getting is the file `filename 2020 v10` (this is the overall latest version).
What I am trying to get is the overall version for each subfolder (`list =filename 2018 v2, filename 2019 v50, filename 2020 v10`).

Comment: @eduardo2111 I'm not sure I understand, perhaps it would be best to open a new question with more detail

Comment: Here I posted this new question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62182435/filter-and-list-specific-file-names

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet that might help your cause:-

```
source = r'C:\Mypath\SubFolder'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith((".xls", ".xlsx",".xlsm")):
            filetoprocess=os.path.join(root,name)
            df=pd.read_excel(filetoprocess, sheetname='Resume', header=1, usecols='A:I')
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use glob library to do this -

```
from glob import glob

filenames = glob('./Folder/pattern*.xlsx')  #pattern is the common pattern in filenames
dataframes = [pd.read_excel(f) for f in filenames] #sequentially read all the files and create a dataframe for each file
master_df = pd.concat(dataframes) #master dataframe after concatenating all the dataframes
```