# Filter and list specific file names

Tags: python, excel

I generated a list of files by writing the following code:

```
files = [file for file in Path(main_directory).rglob('*filename*v*.xlsx')]
```

It retrieves a list of files :

```
files[0] = .../2018/filename 2018 v 1.xlsx
files[1] = .../2019/filename 2019 v 5.xlsx
files[2] = .../2020/filename 2020 v 4.xlsx
files[3] = .../2020/filename 2020 v 5.xlsx
...
files[13] = .../2020/filename 2020 v 10.xlsx
```

What can I do to have an output to give me only the biggest `v` for each year, so I will have an output like this?

```
files[0] = .../2018/filename 2018 v 1.xlsx
files[1] = .../2019/filename 2019 v 5.xlsx
files[2] = .../2020/filename 2020 v 10.xlsx
```

I have to get the biggest `v` which doesn't mean it has the latest modified date, so I can not use that functionality.
I have tried `os.path` and `re` but I am getting no where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the filenames of same years are together you can try this.

```
x=["2018/filename 2018 v 1.xlsx","2019/filename 2019 v 5.xlsx","2020/filename 2020 v 4.xlsx","2020/filename 2020 v 5.xlsx","2020/filename 2020 v 10.xlsx"]
from itertools import groupby
import re
for i,j in groupby(x, lambda x:int(re.findall(r"(?<=filename )\d+", x)[0])):
    print max(j, key=lambda x:int(re.findall(r"(?<=v )\d+(?=\.xlsx)", x)[0]))
```

Output:

```
2018/filename 2018 v 1.xlsx
2019/filename 2019 v 5.xlsx
2020/filename 2020 v 10.xlsx
```

Comment: So your `x` is a list of strings, isn't it?
My `x` is a list of `WindowsPath`. Is it possible to convert an entire list of  `WindowsPath` to strings?

Comment: @eduardo2111 they should already be in strings I guess...if not you can map it to strings

Comment: I am saying this because I get a `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: @eduardo2111 then convert to string using str

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workflow that should work:

For each filename:

```
- Use `os.path` to get just the filename
- use `filename.split(" ")` to split on spaces, which should give you ['filename', '2018', 'v', '1.xlsx']
- Use `replace()` to get rid of `.xlsx` in the last element
- Construct a dict of {year: biggest_version}, which are elements at indexes 1 and 3 from each split
- Celebrate
```

I'll leave the implementation to you! Happy Coding!